# How can following happen in assigning data to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, math, return-value, assign

My understanding is that information flows from right to left in case of "=" operand. i.e. a=b means value of b is transferred to a. And if I change a afterwards, it should not effect value of b. but in the code below, it is happening. Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

```py
df_main=fivminohlc

result=df_main.dtypes

print(result)

result=fivminohlc.dtypes

print(result)

O    float64
H    float64
L    float64
C    float64
V      int64
dtype: object
O    float64
H    float64
L    float64
C    float64
V      int64
dtype: object

df_main['Y1']=(df_main['C']-df_main['O'])/df_main['O'] # I have not touched fivminohlc

df_main['Y'] = np.where((df_main.Y1 > .001), 2, 1) 

df_main['Y'] = np.where((df_main.Y1 < -.001), 0, 1) 

result=df_main.dtypes

print(result)

result=fivminohlc.dtypes

print(result)

O     float64
H     float64
L     float64
C     float64
V       int64
Y1    float64
Y       int32
dtype: object
O     float64
H     float64
L     float64
C     float64
V       int64
Y1    float64
Y       int32
dtype: object
```

How come Y and Y1 are shown in fivminohlc

Comment: When making a [deep copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html), you are still editing the original element.

Answer (score 0):

Because fivminohlc is an instance of a class, when you assign this to df_main, df_main essentially becomes a "pointer" to fivminohlc.

Both df_main and fivminohlc represent the same instance. Therefore by updating df_main, you are also updating fivminohlc.

```
class A:
    num = 1

a = A()
b = a
b.num = 2
print(a.num)
print(a == b)
```

The above code will print

```
2
True
```

See this documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Section 9.3.5. Class and Instance Variables may also be useful.

**Making a copy**

Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html

```py
from pandas import DataFrame

# Instantiate an initial dataframe with columns "Name" and "RoomNumber"
df = DataFrame(columns=["Name", "RoomNumber"])

# Instantiate second_instance which effectively acts as a pointer to df's instance. 
# Also instantiate df_copy using df.copy() which copies the entirety of df into a
# new object.
second_instance = df
df_copy = df.copy()

# Update second_instance to add a new column, and print df. We can clearly see 
# that the change to second_instance affected df.
second_instance["NumberOfGuests"] = {}
print(df.columns)

# Now print df_copy. We can see that the above change to second_instance did not 
# affect df_copy as it is a separate instance.
print(df_copy.columns)
```

This will print:

```
Index(['Name', 'RoomNumber', 'NumberOfGuests'], dtype='object')
Index(['Name', 'RoomNumber'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: I thought that df_main  is a new dataset, I created. Such a fundamental flaw in my understanding. Thanks a ton. However, how to copy a data sets without facing this kind of problem ever

Comment: Also, Why fivminohlc is not a dataframe but a class

Comment: @AIC Answer updated. DataFrame is a Python class. When you call DataFrame() you instantiate an instance of this class. fivminohlc is an instance (object) of the class, but that does not mean that it is not a dataframe. See documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html

Comment: It is worth noting that every variable in Python is an object (an instance of a class). See here: https://jakevdp.github.io/WhirlwindTourOfPython/03-semantics-variables.html